# Sequence no in crystal report XI while duplicate row find in record

Tags: crystal-reports

```
whileprintingrecords; 
Global  numbervar var; 
if (({USP_ExCombWeaponAmmunitionList;1.RegistrationNo}) = 
   previous({USP_ExCombWeaponAmmunitionList;1.RegistrationNo})) then
    var := var
else
    var := var+1;
```

Why above code skip first row sequence no blank and started from second row by sequence 1?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula silently "crashes" as there is no previous record before the first record.

One possibility is to foremost check if the current record is the first record by using `OnFirstRecord`.

In this case assign `1` to `var`.

```
whileprintingrecords; 
Global  numbervar var; 
if OnFirstRecord then
    var := 1
else if (({USP_ExCombWeaponAmmunitionList;1.RegistrationNo}) = 
   previous({USP_ExCombWeaponAmmunitionList;1.RegistrationNo})) then
    var
else
    var := var+1;
```

BTW one can write `var` instead of `var := var`, as this is just a unnecessary reassignment of the variable.